# How does Fiscal Period in Forecasts get set up?

Tags: forecast

When I create new Opportunities it automatically assigns a Fiscal Period of Q4-2019 and is then represented incorrectly in Forecasts despite it having a close date of this Quarter.

I do have Fiscal Year set up in SFDC but that shouldn't impact the Fiscal Period of Opps, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fiscal quarters are derived from the [fiscal year](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_the_fiscal_year.htm&type=5) settings. This will affect your opportunities, forecasts, reports, and other areas where forecast quarters and fiscal years are relevant.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand how that correlates to my new opps having a Fiscal Period of Q4-2019.

Fiscal Years are set up to be standard month end of Feb

Comment: @goldk If you say "FY starts on February", then the fiscal year for 2020 starts February 1st, 2019. If you say "FY ends on February", then the fiscal year for 2019 starts February 1st, 2019. In other words, the first setting moves the next fiscal year into this calendar year, while the latter setting moves the previous fiscal year into this calendar year. By default, when a new opportunity is created, the close date is always the last day of the current fiscal quarter. The current setting basically says that all but one month of 2018 was in 2019's fiscal year.

Comment: This is clearly a me thing not being to fully understand so I may need you to break it down in terms I get it. 

So the standard Fiscal Year is set to 
Fiscal Year Start Month - February
The Month Ending

So that means FY 2018 was Feb 1st, 2017 - Jan 31st, 2018
FY 2019 is Feb 1st, 2018 - Jan 31st, 2019. So we're currently in Q4 2019 right now (Nov, Dec, Jan)

Comment: @goldk Yes. I think may prior description may have been a bit hazy, too, but that's how the "FY end month" mode works. The year the end month falls in defines the FY when using "FY end month", and the year the start month falls in defines the FY when using the "FY start month" mode. You've got it exactly right.

Comment: Ahhh! And my understanding is if we change that we lose quota/forecasting data? I can research that one up, but that helps a lot to articulate in an easy way. Thanks!!

Comment: @goldk The forecast periods are recalculated (including Best Case, Commit, Closed), but the quotas and such would be messed up. I would try this in a sandbox/scratch org/trailhead template/etc before doing the change in your live org.